# Знак процента на оси Y в chart.js

Tags: javascript, графика, chart.js

Я использую библиотеку chart.js для создания графика. И мне надо, чтобы на оси Y, после отображения цифры, показывался знак процента.
[image: график]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339834/how-to-use-percentage-scale-with-chart-js/40438511#40438511), очень схожий вопрос.
А тут пример кода [Тут](https://jsfiddle.net/r71no58a/4/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
   data:{
   labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Percentage',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
},
    options: {
        scales: {
            
            yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
            
                   min: 0,
                   max: 100,
                   callback: function(value){return value+ "%"}
                },  
                                scaleLabel: {
                   display: true,
                   labelString: "Percentage"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, наверное ^-^